# ScrollView overlapping when stepper is selected

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate, uistepper

Ok I have an unexpected run time issue/ error with my iOS app. I put a scroll view and stepper which increment based on items parsed from a webservice. Now whe scroll view populates when user select the Stepper and now that is working fine.

My question is how can I avoid the app from overlapping like in the screenshot below.[image: overlapping]

Comment: Scroll views are meant to do this if your scroll view frame is set to fill the view. Simply change the frame of the scroll view however you create it to be the frame minus the height of the stepper and segment control

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to simply refresh the table data each time a stepper is selected.

This is the lone of code that removed all the overlapping issue.

```
[self.tableView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperView)];
```